# Networking issue between GCP instances - can't init Cockroach cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, terraform, connection, cockroachdb

I deployed [CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/) on [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/)'s Compute Engine using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/).
I mainly followed the tutorial - [Deploy CockroachDB on Google Cloud Platform GCE (Insecure)](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/deploy-cockroachdb-on-google-cloud-platform-insecure#step-6-initialize-the-cluster).

My issue is related to networking difficulties. Specifically, I'm encountering problems establishing connections between my local machine and VM instances, as well as between the VM instances themselves.

Here's the situation: I'm not being able to launch the built-in SQL client from my local machine ([Step 7. Test the cluster](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/deploy-cockroachdb-on-google-cloud-platform-insecure#step-7-test-the-cluster)). Could this be due to the deployment of GCE's TCP Proxy Load Balancing service?

Below are the previous commands executed.

- Start cluster:

  - instance1: `cockroach start --insecure --advertise-addr=<internal IP instance1> --join=<internal IP instance1>,<internal IP instance2> --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25 --background`
  - instance2: `cockroach start --insecure --advertise-addr=<internal IP instance2> --join=<internal IP instance1>,<internal IP instance2> --cache=.25 --max-sql-memory=.25 --background`
- Perform a one-time initialization of cluster:

  - Local machine: `cockroach init --insecure --host=<external IP instance1>`
- Launch the built-in SQL client:

  - Local machine:

```
# $ cockroach sql --insecure --host=google_compute_global_address.cockroachdb_tcp_lb_static_ipv4.address
#
# Welcome to the CockroachDB SQL shell.
# All statements must be terminated by a semicolon.
# To exit, type: \q.
#
ERROR: server closed the connection.
Is this a CockroachDB node?
unexpected EOF
Failed running "sql"
```

Networking and me don't get along, so I apologize if it is not clear. Every help would be very welcome, I'm a bit desperate.

*Note: below is the Terraform code executed, which I hope can be of assistance to you or anyone seeking help.*

instance.tf:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "cockroachdb_instance" {
  count        = var.instance_count
  name         = "cockroachdb-instance${count.index}"
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  tags         = ["ssh-server", "cockroachdb", "cockroachdb-instances"]
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = var.image
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.cockroachdb_network.self_link
    access_config {
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.static[count.index].address
    }
  }
  metadata = {
    sshKeys        = "${var.ssh_user}:${file(var.ssh_pub_key_file)}"
    startup-script = <<-EOT
      #!/bin/bash
      curl -L https://binaries.cockroachdb.com/cockroach-v23.1.8.linux-amd64.tgz | tar -xz
      sudo cp -i cockroach-v23.1.8.linux-amd64/cockroach /usr/local/bin/
      sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/cockroach
      sudo cp -i cockroach-v23.1.8.linux-amd64/lib/libgeos.so /usr/local/lib/cockroach/
      sudo cp -i cockroach-v23.1.8.linux-amd64/lib/libgeos_c.so /usr/local/lib/cockroach/
      EOT
  }
}

resource "google_compute_address" "static" {
  count = var.instance_count
  name  = "ipv4-address-${count.index}"
}
```

load-balancing.tf:

```
# Global static IPv4 addresses
resource "google_compute_global_address" "cockroachdb_tcp_lb_static_ipv4" {
  name       = "cockroachdb-tcp-lb-static-ipv4"
  ip_version = "IPV4"
}

# Global forwarding rule
resource "google_compute_global_forwarding_rule" "cockroachdb_ipv4_forwarding_rule" {
  name       = "cockroachdb-ipv4-forwarding-rule"
  ip_address = google_compute_global_address.cockroachdb_tcp_lb_static_ipv4.address
  target     = google_compute_target_tcp_proxy.cockroachdb_target_tcp_proxy.self_link
  port_range = "26257"
}

# TCP proxy
resource "google_compute_target_tcp_proxy" "cockroachdb_target_tcp_proxy" {
  name            = "cockroachdb-target-tcp-proxy"
  backend_service = google_compute_backend_service.cockroachdb_backend_service.self_link
}

# Backend service
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "cockroachdb_backend_service" {
  name          = "cockroachdb-backend-service"
  timeout_sec   = 300
  protocol      = "TCP"
  health_checks = [
    google_compute_health_check.cockroachdb_health_check.self_link,
  ]
  backend {
    group           = google_compute_instance_group.cockroachdb_instance_group.self_link
    max_utilization = 0.8
  }
}

# Health check
resource "google_compute_health_check" "cockroachdb_health_check" {
  name                = "cockroachdb-health-check"
  check_interval_sec  = 10
  timeout_sec         = 5
  unhealthy_threshold = 3
  healthy_threshold   = 2
  http_health_check {
    port         = 8080
    request_path = "/health?ready=1"
  }
}

# Instance group
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "cockroachdb_instance_group" {
  name        = "cockroachdb-instance-group"
  instances   = google_compute_instance.cockroachdb_instance[*].self_link
  named_port {
    name = "tcp26257"
    port = 26257
  }
}
```

network.tf:

```
# Network resource
resource "google_compute_network" "cockroachdb_network" {
  name                    = "cockroachdb-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "true"
}

# Firewall rules
resource "google_compute_firewall" "ssh-server" {
  name          = "default-allow-ssh-terraform"
  network       = google_compute_network.cockroachdb_network.name
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  target_tags   = ["ssh-server"]
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["22"]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_firewall" "cockroachdb" {
  name          = "default-allow-cockroachdb"
  network       = google_compute_network.cockroachdb_network.name
  source_ranges = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  target_tags   = ["cockroachdb"]
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["26257", "8080"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be pushy but help would be very welcome, I'm a bit desperate.

Comment: I cannot claim to know about Cockroach but is:
--host=google_compute_global_address.cockroachdb_tcp_lb_static_ipv4.address
what you were typing at the command line?

What happens if you type-in an actual hostname or IP address where your DB is running?